# Transactional File Access and Caching in JBoss AS 5

Tags: java, file-io, transactions, jboss5.x

We need to **locally store a cache on a File System through JBoss 5**. The files we need to store **are big (~50 Mbyte)** and there are many consumer (through WS on JBoss) that read these files and one producer (JBoss Biz Logic) that creates the last one.

Because there are concurrent read and write problems, I would like to know if there is a solution to manage the transactions on File in a FileSystem (that could be NAS or CIFS or other thing).

I looked at "JBossCache" but in the documentation they say that File System access is only for test purpose. I looked at JBoss ["Transactional File I/O"](http://www.jboss.org/jbosstm/fileio/) too but I don't know if it works.

Probably we need a framework to manage the caching layer and another framework to store this data with transaction on FS. A solution could be to store data in a DBMS but I don't like very much this solution.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so please give me some help :-)

Answer (score 1):

See if [XADisk](http://xadisk.java.net/) can help.